# C++ access to Int variable from two threads. Thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, int

- There is an `int` variable that holds balance.
- Many threads reference this `int` variable.
- Each thread does their job and can access to `int` pointer at any time and add some value.

Is it thread safe to do this? Or I should use `mutex lock`?

Here is example (it works without any issues, just need to be sure if forever):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

int someInt=0;

class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    MyThread(){start();}
    void run()
    {
        for(int n=0;n<1000;n++)someInt-=1;
        for(int n=0;n<1000;n++)someInt+=2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug()<<"someInt="<<someInt;      
    QTimer::singleShot(5000,&a,SLOT(quit()));

    MyThread thread1;
    MyThread thread2;

    a.exec();

    //There always 2000 output, and there is no issue, 
    //just need to be sure if forever.
    qDebug()<<"someInt="<<someInt;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give a short code sample (not the complete code), that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Read the info page for multithreading: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/multithreading/info

Comment: Thank you. I'll read it and try to make some code for example.

Comment: I have added code, please look.

Comment: Also herer is my another question: is reading of "double" on x64 machine thread safe?

Comment: No data access is threadsafe unless specifically designed to be threadsafe. You can make it threadsafe though, similarly to ints.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use std::atomic<quint64> and std::atomic<double>.
Looks like it works good only for "+=", "-=" etc. operators, but it useles if use someInt=someInt+1. And std::atomic<double> does not have this operators. But I know direction. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe and you should either use a [lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

Comment: Is lock or atomic ooperations faster?

Comment: @IGHOR: No simple answer. It may be faster to sum up the totals only in the end, and keep per-thread partial sums.

Comment: It not possible to keep peer partial sums, because each thread should get access to this int realtime.

Comment: The variable doesn't influence in any way how the two threads behave, so there is no reason not to update it only once. Unless of course there is a requirement that you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: Go with atomic. If you don't use c++11, gcc implements them anyway with some special functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using C++11 atomic variables. But do I have ABA problem there?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code. Still, the question remains why you need to update the variable in every loop rotation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  How do we easily prove that it's not safe ? For example, output another number instead of 2000 ?

Comment: Just look at the code, @LewisChan: An object is modified by two threads without synchronization. That is already enough to not be thread-safe, which means you can't expect any particular result. It doesn't mean that it fails every time or that it fails often, not even that it fails at all, it just means you don't have any guarantees. It may "work" on your machine bit fail on a different one or with a different compiler.